# Dual monitors dual OS's?

Tags: multiple-monitors, operating-systems

Quick and painless, I have a partitioned SSD with win 7 and Linux back box on it and I just bought a second monitor. I was wondering if one monitor could display win7 and the other back box off the same drive? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're dual booting, no. Only one OS can be running at a time.

What you could do is virtualize the second OS. e.g. boot into Windows and use a program like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player) to run a virtual machine on which you install Black Box.

You can then have the console for the Virtual Machine on the other screen, possibly full screen depending on which software you use, and interact with them at the same time.

Comment: I was just going to make the same answer. The only thing I was going to add is that it is possible to mount the existing OS installation as the primary HD in most VM software. This will allow him to use the actual partition he is already using. Expect a lot of driver errors on first boot though.

Comment: Thats what i thought, was hoping for some SU voodoo or something haha thanks for your help guys

Comment: Very good point @krowe. It should also be possible to do a Physical to Virtual conversion using VMware Standalone Converter (I come from a VMware environment) or something similar if you wanted to fully embrace the visualization of the second OS.